# Data change in spark pipe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So I am piping some binary data using RDD.pipe() function to "cat", when I receive the data it is changed so i can't work with it.any I die how to fix it?
I'm using python3
The code and a par of the data is as follows:

```
line = sc.binaryFiles("files/pipevids")
line.map(lambda x:x[1]).pipe("cat").take(1)
```

and the original data:

```
b'RIFF\xeaU\n\x00AVI LIST\x963\x00\x00hdrlavih8\x00\x00\x005\x82\x00\x00\x08L\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\t\x00\x00<\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x80\x07\x00\x008\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00LIST\x10\x11\x00\x00strlstrh8\x00\x00\x00vidsFMP4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x00\x00\x00\x11x\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x078\x04strfX\x00\x00\x00W\x00\x00\x00\x80\x07\x00\x008\x04\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00FMP4\x00\xec^\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xb0\x01\x00\x00\x01\xb5\x89\x13\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01 \x00\xc4\x8d\x88\x00\xf5<\x04\x87\x14C\x00\x00\x01\xb2Lavc57.89.100\x00JUNK\x18\x10\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0000dc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
```

The data I receive is:

```
b\'RIFF\\xeaU\\n\\x00AVI LIST\\x963\\x00\\x00hdrlavih8\\x00\\x00\\x005\\x82\\x00\\x00\\x08L\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x10\\t\\x00\\x00<\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x10\\x00\\x80\\x07\\x00\\x008\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00LIST\\x10\\x11\\x00\\x00strlstrh8\\x00\\x00\\x00vidsFMP4\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x1e\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00<\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x11x\\x00\\x00\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xff\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\x078\\x04strfX\\x00\\x00\\x00W\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x80\\x07\\x00\\x008\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x18\\x00FMP4\\x00\\xec^\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\xb0\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x01\\xb5\\x89\\x13\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01 \\x00\\xc4\\x8d\\x88\\x00\\xf5<\\x04\\x87\\x14C\\x00\\x00\\x01\\xb2Lavc57.89.100\\x00JUNK\\x18\\x10\\x00\\x00\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x0000dc\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\
```

with an extra '\'

I would like to pipe this to ffmpeg with this command

```
"ffmpeg -loglevel debug -y -i pipe:0 -f avi pipe:1"
```

Comment: Can you print the `type()` of that? I assume one is bytes, the other is str?

Comment: Can you explain what purpose `cat` provides you here?

Comment: No this is just the sample I piepe to an external program named FFMPEG the actual code is: line.map(lambda x:x[1]).pipe("ffmpeg -loglevel debug -y -i pipe:0 -f avi pipe:1").take(1)

Comment: I don't think you need a pipe here... You want to `map` an `os.system` call... Besides, I'm not  even sure `ffmpeg` accepts binary data

Comment: ffmpeg does accept binary data if cat <filename> and pipe it to binary it works fine, the thing is I am loading the binary data into a RDD, I don't want to store data an download for every process.

Comment: What do you mean by store and download? `take(1)` is already downloading any previous computation

Comment: By download I mean, when i give the input file in ffmpeg I should download the file from hdfs and give to ffmpeg, I'm trying to see if i can pipe the actual binary data to it. what do you think I should do? is there another tool?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `pipe` requires a `str` object.

```
>>> str(b'RIFF\xeaU\n\x00AVI')
"b'RIFF\\xeaU\\n\\x00AVI'"
>>>
```

If you want specific representation, you should `decode` data before passing to `pipe`.

Unfortunately the result is automatically decoded as UTF-8, so you cannot do much here.

Comment: I actually want to parse the binary data not the string Because ffmpeg needs binary data in the input